# SQL filter out rows with duplicate cell value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a big query that's returning rows where one of the colums has duplicated values, for example:

```
| sysid | col1 | col2
| A     |  1   |  2
| A     |  2   |  3
| B     |  1   |  4
```

`sysid` is the column I want to filter by, so in the above example I only want the last row of output because A appears more than once.  I tried to do this to filter them out:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp (SysId VARCHAR(10), col1 INT);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('A', 1);

WITH cte AS (
   SELECT * FROM #temp
), sysids AS (
   SELECT SysId FROM #temp GROUP BY Sysid HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SysId FROM sysids);

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

I expected that final select would only contain the B row, in the above example . I'm still getting all of them though, and I don't understand why.

Obviously in this specific example I don't need the `cte` part but my real query is pretty complex with multiple unions.

Comment: The problem is you're not linking the `exists` back to the outer query (such as `where sysids.sysid = #temp.sysid`). As it is currently written, at least one `sysid` does exist in `sysids`, so the where clause is true for each row. The query as written is no different from, say, `where exists (select object_id from sys.objects)` since it has no relation to the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.SysId,t.col1,COUNT(1)OVER(PARTITION BY t.SysID) AS [cnt] 
    FROM #temp t
) 
SELECT c.SysId,c.col1
FROM cte c WHERE c.cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated, aggregating subyquery and `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM #temp t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ''
                                FROM #temp t2
                                WHERE t2.sysid = t1.sysid
                                HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: Oh, interesting approach. I'd been thinking of just using a NOT IN. Would the NOT EXISTS you have be expected to perform better, or is it volume dependant?

Comment: @Ben: With an index on `sysid` I could imagine this to be quite efficient. At least it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (SysId VARCHAR(10), col1 INT);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('A', 1);

WITH cte AS (
   SELECT * FROM #temp
), sysids AS (
   SELECT SysId FROM #temp GROUP BY Sysid HAVING COUNT(SysId) =1
   )
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE SysId IN (SELECT SysId FROM sysids);

DROP TABLE #temp;
```